# Putting the <tr> data into the table with only one header

Tags: php, html, html-table

I made the changes and now they are in the same table but not under the correct column and the address is not completely rendering.  It appears to only be taking the first word which is numbers and leaving off the rest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ6I4.png)It

```
    $header = false;

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "CALL Webc") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());


  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($header == false ) {
      echo "<table border=1>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>TDate</th>
            <th>Student Type</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>";


        $header = true;
  }
  echo "<form action=update_students.php method=post>";

   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=CustomerID value=" .$row["CustomerID"].   "  </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=active  value=" .$row["active"].   " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=TDate  value=" .$row["TDate"].   "  </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=StudentType value=" .$row["StudentType"].  "  </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=FirstName  value=" .$row["FirstName"].  "   </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=LastName  value=" .$row["LastName"].  " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=Address  value=" .$row["Address"].  " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=City  value=" .$row["City"].  " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=State value=" .$row["State"].  " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=Zip  value=" .$row["Zip"].  " </td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=Email value=" .$row["Email"].  " </td></tr>";



       echo "<td>".  "<input type=submit name=update value=update>".   "</td>";
    echo "<td>".  "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete>".   "</td>";



        echo '<br />';
     echo "</form>";
  }
```

Comment: Need them in one table with correct data in the correct column under the correct Header Name is what I meant.

Comment: Add the language tag too (php?). That's not valid HTML as the tags should be closed, the th and td should be in tr tags, and the table should be inside of of the form https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here  in output you missed  in 
here is an expample from you code:

```
echo "<tr>" . "<input type=text name=CustomerID value=" .$row["CustomerID"].   "  </tr>";
```

should be written a

```
echo "<tr><td>" . "<input type=text name=CustomerID value=" .$row["CustomerID"].   "  </td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks  -  That is a slight improvement but the second column "Active"  should have the 'yes" go under that header but it appearing right underneath the "CustomerID".  Is there a way to increment it to the next column?

Comment: can you just share the html code for the same. I can figure out a solution for that.

Comment: It is all in the table now but not horizontally.  How would I get them into the right columns